# Cannot log into MySQL

Tags: 16.04, mysql, wordpress, moodle

I have a very common problem with my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/MySQL 5.7.18/WordPress running on a Digital Ocean droplet with 2 CPU, 40GB SSD and 16GB RAM. The droplet is only running one site and has hardly any traffic because it is still under development.

1. I cannot connect via 'mysql -u root -p'.
2. I cannot use the 'sudo mysqlsecureinstallation' script.

Every time after entering the password I get the dreaded "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" error message.

This appears to be a very common problem. I wasted a whole day following all the usual recommendations, such as reinstalling MySQL, with and without prior uninstall, crossgrading to MariaDB and back to MySQL, all to none avail. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, the WordPress site is working fine. The problem only became apparent when I added Moodle to the installation and got stuck at the point where you need to create the Moodle tables. Since I cannot log into the MySQL server, I'm now stuck.

Comment: Is wordpress using a mysql connection?, if so, is it using a different user than root and how it was created?

Comment: Wordpress is indeed using a different MySQL user. It was automatically created by Digital Ocean's one-click Ubuntu/MySQL/Wordpress installation.

Comment: Navigate into wordpress config file and check the host and port that it's using to connect to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you'v started mysql.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root
```

if you'v not set mysql password you should not include  `-p`, notice you have to specify the host

Comment: MySQL is running. I tried your suggestions but with the same result: 

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'