# Can't log into MySQL with any user in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, mysql

I have been trying to start Airflow as systemd and I have run into a problem. I have followed the instructions in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056403/9621172 and some others and somehow now I cannot logging into MySQL. I have seen a couple of post related ([Cannot log into MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922108/cannot-log-into-mysql), [Can't log into MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120718/cant-log-into-mysql)) but I cannot follow the instructions there.

With the following commands

```
sudo mysql -u root
sudo mysql -u ubuntu
sudo mysql
mysql
```

I get the error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root/user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Even after stopping the server with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` and starting the mysqld configuration with `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &` I am not able to enter to the database anymore. What could I do?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `-p` after? So that it looks like this:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. What does exactly means -p?

Comment: It means prompt for password :-)